# How to get Drupal 8 View to Accept Parameter as argument?

Tags: views, 8

I created a view that shows a bunch of cars. I allow you to filter by brand using an exposed block. If you filter, it results in a path like this:

```
/?brand=Volkswagen
```

I want brand to have the path:

```
/Volkswagen
```

instead.

How would one do this with Views? Or is this something that should rather be attempted with rewrite rules in htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a contextual filter. In the "Configure contextual filter" menu select "Provide default value". For type choose Raw value from url.

There is more info on contextual filters in this article.

http://redcrackle.com/blog/adding-contextual-filter-view-drupal-8

If you are using taxonomies and want to use the name instead of id in the url you need to setup the relationships first and use name as the contextual filter.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you maybe want a taxonomy rather than create your own view?

You can create re-write rules for the alias using something like [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) and then you could get the url to look like you want.